# Storing zero after decimal point

Tags: sql-server, types, coldfusion, sqldatatypes

Right now I'm working on a project using CFM and  MSSQL.
I have a numbering data in a field. I've set the DATATYPE as float.

example of the data:

3.1,3.2,3.3........,3.10, 3.11

My problem:

1. it appeared that 3.10 doesn't exist. instead it comes as 3.1, which means I have two of 3.1 number.
2. when i sort the data, it displayed as:
   3.1, 3.1, 3.11, 3.2, 3.3 .. .. etc.

I don't know what went wrong.
Please help.

Comment: for float type 3.1 == 3.10 == 3.100 etc

Comment: Nothing went "wrong" 3.10 = 3.1, just like all numbers that are stored it's leaving off the trailing 0's.

Comment: dygta: Nothing went 'wrong': you are confusing presentation with storage.

Comment: @Random You forgot 3.1==3.1000 =)

Comment: What do these numbers represent?  Are they prices?  Weights?  Chapter and verse?  If they are prices/weight, you may want to avoid float, as you will get weird rounding errors.  If they are chapter/verse, use varchar.

Comment: @JohnFx: I don't think he/she did. Those two examples were just chosen randomly. :)

Comment: The downvotes seem a little harsh. Sure the question is naive, but it is a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

If you need 3.1 and 3.10 to represent different values for whatever unholy abomination of math you are trying to accomplish, you will need to use a textual datatype like varchar.

As long as you are using a numeric type, SQL and every other programming platform will likely enforce the universal laws of mathematics where 3.1 and 3.10 are the same value.

Comment: i'm actually making a list. sort of like this. 2 fields; No and Item. now i've change the data type (No) as varchar. and in the code, i've set it to ORDER BY No. <br>However, the output is this <br>
4.1,4.10,4.11,4.12,4.13,4.2,4.3,4.4, etc<br>

Comment: If the part to the right and left of the decimal represents two distinct values, put it in two integer fields instead of jamming them together. That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the precision as well, either make a new column to store that information, or store it as a string, which you can parse into a float before you need it as a number.  Strings sort nicely, too.

Comment: the thing is, i only need it as a number just to do the sorting/order by so that it looks proper... i don't know if i did the wrong code :( i'm new with this programming thing btw..

Comment: @dygta Well then, the actual answer is then you did nothing wrong, and have to realize that 1 is actually the exact same number as 1.0